# where condition with laravel has many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get record with where condition in laravel elquent query.
Here is my relationship method.

```
public function OrdersReferrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'referred_by');
}

public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'referred_by')->with('referrals', 'OrdersReferrals');
}
```

Here is my controller query

```
$userData = User::with('adminuserrreferrals')
   ->where('id', $id)
   ->where('payout_status', 'pending')
   ->get();
```

Problem Is that this query, where condition is work for only user table. while I need this `->where('payout_status','pending')` for orders table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I think you want something like this (to filter `payout_status` field in `orders` table):

```
$userData = User::with('adminuserrreferrals')
    ->whereHas(['adminuserrreferrals' => function($query) {
        $query->where('payout_status', 'pending');
    }])
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->get();
```

I hope the `adminuserrreferrals` relationship method for `ordsrs` table is defined correctly in `User` model and there is an `Order` model exists.